# Issue with erase or transparent stroke using CoreGraphics framework

Tags: iphone, core-graphics

In one of my apps, am trying to erase/transparent stroke a part of `UIImage` which am drawing using CoreGraphics framework (`CGContextRef` etc..). Well in the process I am able to clear the drawing in one shot by calling "removeAllObjects" message, but I was not able to figure out, how to erase a part of the drawing image. Gosh!! I sat the whole day but still no results, now its killing me. Please guys help me out from here. In short, my requirement is something like an eraser which can erase a part of of my drawing image. Appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 5):

Just do `CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear)`

This call changes the color blending mode in such a way that drawing operations would be clearing bitmap instead of drawing with color.

To switch back to normal rendering do `CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal)`

Using different blending modes can be very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Generally, `CGContext`s are additive-only canvases--that is you can only add more paint, not remove any existing paint that you've put on them. If your canvas was white to start with, you can paint over with white to fake and erase operation.

A simple solution would be to manually clear out the areas of the backing bitmap are being erasing.

A complex solution is to store all the painting operations that the user has entered and deform them as a result of the erase operation (this will also make adding an undo mode simple)

Note: There is the `CGContextClearRect` function, but it generally only works as expected on bitmap contexts.

Comment: i had tried with CGContextSetBlendMode,may b am going on a direction, i just could not figure out with that.removeAllObjects is been called as am using a NSMutableArray to keep the drawing objects in that buffer, which am clearing by calling the removeAllObjects message.My app has three tab bar items, one to save the drawing image, 2nd one is to clear the image & 3rd one is to clear/erase a portion of the drawing image (something like eraser in MSPaint) which i just posted here as my query. 
Please help me on this as am still not very good @ CoreGraphics/2D physics.

Comment: Or your first solution to fake and erase, I can try. To be honest here i dont have any prior knowledge on CGContextClearRect, so need to google out more on that.

Comment: Your best bet would be to use `CGBitmapContextCreate` and supply your own backing buffer--then you can modify it directly using your own erasing code