# Ios auto map reveal fog of war effect on grid

Tags: ios, dictionary, show

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do a fog of war type effect for a game I'm doing. the effect should reveal squares that you have been on. The effect should reveals squares from a 40x40 grid as you move. I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this. I know I could make the map as an image and then add an array of 40 x 40 images that cover it and hide them , then reveal as you walk on the square this seems pretty inefficient. My map also sits on a scroll view so you can pan around the map and resize it to zoom in and out. Im not sure if there are any better functions to reveal just certain parts of an image. Anyone have any ideas how to best handle this is the most efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to cover a view and then reveal part of it. In a way, that's just an like an eraser tool. Here are a few things that might help you.

- Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227769/making-an-eraser-tool-for-a-paint-app-in-ios) about creating an eraser effect.
- Here is a [blog post](http://craigcoded.com/2010/12/08/erase-top-uiview-to-reveal-content-underneath/) about wiping away an image to show a view underneath

The important part is using this to clear away the fog (if it was drawn with CoreGraphics):

```
CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeClear);
```